# I need a simple dropdown menu OnChange/Select in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help on something really simple.

I have 2 dropdown boxes on a form:

```
<select name="OfficeLocation" >
   <option value="" ></option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">New York</option>
   <option value="2" >Los Angeles</option>
   <option value="3" >San Francisco</option>
</select>

<select name="OfficePhone">
   <option value="" ></option>
   <option value="1">(718)555-1212</option>
   <option value="2" >(213)555-1212</option>
   <option value="3" >(415)555-1214</option>
</select>
```

The second one is "Read Only"
All I need to know is how can I change the value of "OfficePhone" by changing the value of "OfficeLocation"? using either a simple JavaScript or JSP Command
Thanks

Comment: This isn't a coding service: what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I suffered a stroke and am forgetting simple things

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need an event handler function for the OfficeLocation select and an id for the second select.

```
<select name="OfficeLocation" onchange="eHandler">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">New York</option>
<option value="2" >Los Angeles</option>
<option value="3" >San Francisco</option>
</select>

<select name="OfficePhone" id="oPhone">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="1">(718)555-1212</option>
<option value="2" >(213)555-1212</option>
<option value="3" >(415)555-1214</option>
</select>
```

You have to implement your event handler in your script, like this:

```
function eHandler(){
  var secondSelect = document.getElementById('oPhone');
  secondSelect.value = //the value you want to be selected
}
```

Comment: I recently suffered a stroke and am trying to get my head back in the game but am forgetting simple things, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use a script like the following:

```
<script>
    menu1 = document.getElementsByName('OfficeLocation')[0];
    menu2 = document.getElementsByName('OfficePhone')[0];
    menu1.onchange = function(){      
      menu2.value = menu1.value;
    }
  </script>
```

Here you are using the `onchange` event to initiate a function that make the value on the second menu `menu2` equals to the selected value of the first menu `menu1`.

An online demo is [**here**](http://jsbin.com/pocobacaxe/edit?html,output)

Notice that: the script should be placed after your elements.